# How do I Implicitly Differentiate this equation?

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation

My equation is $y=x^{y^2}$

I did the $\ln$ of both sides, then I tried implicit differentiation. I got $$y'= \frac{x^{y^2} y^2}{x}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$y=x^{y^2}$$
$$\ln y=y^2\ln x$$
$$\frac{1}{y}\cdot\frac{dy}{dx}=2y\frac{dy}{dx}\ln x+\frac{y^2}{x}$$

$$\left(\frac{1}{y}-2y\ln x\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x}$$

$$\left(\frac{1-2y^2\ln x}{y}\right)\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2}{x}$$
$$\begin{align}\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{y^3}{x(1-2y^2\ln x)}\\
&=\frac{y\cdot y^2}{x(1-2y\cdot y\ln x)}\\
\end{align}$$

> [$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{y^2x^{y^2-1}}{1-2yx^{y^2}\ln x}$$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&f=ob&i=differentiate%20y%3Dx%5E(y%5E2))

Comment: thank you for the detailed steps

Comment: i am confused tho about the last step, the answer in the gray box. how did u get that from the step before?

Comment: @Kaaagome you can also do this by $-f_x/f_y$ =$dy\dx$

Comment: @Integrator means?